# Internal hard drives not recognise after ubuntu installation. Please help!

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, hard-drive, filesystem

I have 3 internal hard disks in my PC. One containing my OS windows 10, and the other two contains no operating system and are both formatted with ReFS containing data.

It is only after I added a fourth internal hard disk containing an old windows 10, updated it and installing ubuntu onto the new drive when both my ReFS drives becomes inaccessible in windows. When I try to access the drives in windows explorer, it gives the error "the volume repair was not successful". What could caused this, and how do I solve it? I suspect this has something to do with grub, however the two drives were not touched during the ubuntu installation, plus ReFS isn't compatible with ubuntu anyway. The two drives are relatively new and modern. So I doubt they are faulty.

I have isolated the ubuntu harddrive, leaving the windows and refs harddrives in my PC however it still doesn't work.

Comment: ReFS has only read-only and proprietary support for linux. (reference : https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Read-Only-ReFS-Linux-Driver)

Comment: Yes, what I meant was after the installation of Ubuntu, Windows 10 no longer is able to mount my ReFS drives. It shows as RAW.